Dependence of Chemical Potential in Derivation of Clapeyron Equation
The "standard" derivation of the Clapeyron equation begins with considering two phases $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that are in equilibrium. The claim made is that
$$\mu^\alpha(T,P) = \mu^\beta(T,P)$$
so that
$$d\mu^\alpha = d\mu^\beta$$
and therefore
$$\overline{V_\alpha} dP - \overline{S_\alpha} dT = \overline{V_\beta} dP - \overline{S_\beta} dT$$
and the rest of the derivation is simple manipulation. However, it is my understanding that chemical potential depends on pressure, temperature, and the concentration of the various substances present. In this case, since we have only two substances present, chemical potential should depend on temperature, pressure, and the mole fraction of phase $\alpha$: $\mu = \mu(T,P,x_\alpha)$. I don't understand why we can ignore the dependence of $\mu$ on $x_\alpha$ in the above derivation of the Claperyon equation.
When I asked my pchem professor about this, she suggested that I should think about this as us considering the system in equilibrium and considering the variation of equilibrium chemical potential with pressure and temperature (i.e. following the equilibrium curve on the phase diagram). The way I understand this is that at a given temperature and pressure, the equilibrium mole fraction of $x_\alpha$ is fixed. Therefore, $x_\alpha = x_\alpha(T,P)$ is a function of temperature and pressure and we get $\mu^\text{eq} = \mu(T,P,x_\alpha(T,P)).$ However, now we have:

and the above derivation of the Clapeyron equation does not carry through. Cleary my understanding of this interpretation (or possibly this interpretation itself) is incorrect. I was hoping someone could clarify exactly is going on here.

CHP would depend on mole fraction for mixtures, not on mole fraction of pure condensed phase wrt the total substance content. Ice melting point is not the function of water/ice ratio

"only two substances present" There are two phases, not two substances.

And, in binary (and higher) phase diagrams one includes the appropriate concentration terms. Still, in equilibrium, the chemical potential of any one component is constant. Your example has only one component, and it is constant.

The chemical potentials of any phases and components are equal.
